# put javascript into jquery .html function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to replace the contents of a div with other contents, both contents are JavaScript codes, however, when I press the button that calls the function, the whole page refreshes, and the new JavaScript in the function gets loaded onto the page (and looks corrupted too)

Here's my JavaScript function that I use

```
function refresh(){
alert("button pressed");
$("#tweet1").html('<script>new TWTR.Widget({version: 2,  type: "search",  search: "#abbaseya",  interval: 15000,  subject: "widget",  width: 300,  height: 360,theme: {    shell: {      background: "#8ec1da",      color: "#ffffff"    },tweets:{background:"#ffffff",color:"#444444",links:"#1985b5"}},features:{scrollbar:true,loop:true,live:true,behavior:"default"}}).render().start();<\/script>');
}
```

What am I doing wrong? tweet1 is just a div with an id, and the function above gets called by a button

here's the button I'm using, I have a form in the html

```
<form style="float:right; ">
        <input type="text"/><input type="button" value="Refresh" onclick="refresh()"/>
        </form>
```

Comment: is the button you are using a form button ?

Comment: That really doesn't make sense; why wouldn't you simply code that JavaScript directly into the event handler?  Anyway the page is probably refreshing because the element you click on is either an `<a>` tag or a "submit" element.

Comment: yes the button is a form button

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's really no reason to dynamically inject an inline script tag into a DOM element. Just execute the body of the script tag as regular JavaScript.

```
function refresh() {
  alert("button pressed");
  new TWTR.Widget({version: 2,  type: "search",  search: "#abbaseya",  interval: 15000,      
  subject: "widget",  width: 300,  height: 360,theme: {    shell: {      background:
   "#8ec1da",      color: "#ffffff"    },tweets:
  {background:"#ffffff",color:"#444444",links:"#1985b5"}},features:
  {scrollbar:true,loop:true,live:true,behavior:"default"}}).render().start();
  return false; // prevent refresh
}
```

Comment: I tried your solution, the page still refreshes altogether and I'm presented only with that piece of javascript in the whole page.

Comment: It will still refresh if there's an error, as it will never get to "return false". So remove the "return false" and look for an error message (in Chrome devtools, firebug, whatever).

Comment: only in IE it shows an error within the twitter widget itself =( document.getElementsByTagName(...).0' is null or not an object

Comment: Different problem then. In that case, start a separate question with subject and tags about the twitter widget

Comment: I'm marking this as the answer since the code is ok, even though the problem turned out to be with the widget itself